# iOS 256 Colors (VGA) to RGB

Tags: iphone, ios, uicolor, cgcolor, cgcolorspace

I'd like to convert a VGA color (256 colors; 8 bit) to a RGB color on iOS.

Is it possible to compute this or do I have to use color tables (using CGColorSpaceCreateIndexed).

UIColor does not support 256 Colors.

Thanks :)

Comment: I took the liberty of changing "256 bit" into "256 colors".

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. VGA colors in the 8-bit color space *are* RGB colors. They are made up of individual red, green, and blue color components. The fact that there are a maximum of 256 colors is irrelevant. You don't need to create any kind of color index table or compute anything.

Comment: Maybe I should elaborate. I'm working on a port of a DOS game to iOS. I get a uint8 as color (one component, 8 bit) and need to convert this into RGB (three components).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere, the title you're porting should have set the palette. On the VGA, the 256 colours are mapped through a table that the programmer has previously set to convert them into 18 bit RGB colour (at a uniform 6 bits per channel). If you're running the original title through emulation then watch for writes to ports 0x3c6, 0x3c8 and 0x3c9 or calls to the BIOS via int 10h, with ax = 0x1010 (to set a single colour) or 0x1012 (to set a range). If you have the original code, obviously look for the source of the palette table.

In drawing terms, you can keep the palette yourself, for example as a C-style array of 256 CGColorRefs, or use CGColorSpaceCreateIndexed as you suggest (ignore Apple's slight documentation error; the colour table can contain up to 256 entries, not up to 255) probably with a bitmap context to just pass your buffer off to CoreGraphics and forget about it.

I expect the remapping will be performed on the CPU, so if that gets a bit too costly then consider using GL ES 2.x and writing a suitable pixel shader — you'd upload your actual image as, say, a luminance (ie, single channel) texture, plus a 256x1 texture where the colour at each spot is a palette entry, then write a shader that reads from the first texture for the current texture coordinates and uses that value to index the second.